# what's wrong with this $.inArray method?

Tags: jquery, arrays

in the code below towards the bottom im checking if `[number1, number2, number1+ number2]` is not inside the array `wrongQs` if it is int push the array,`[number1, number2, number1+ number2]`  into `wrongQs`

```
    $(document).ready( function(){

        var wrong = 0
        wrongQs = []
        clicked = false

         number1 = ~~(Math.random() * 10);
         number2 = ~~(Math.random() * 10);
        $(".numbers").children().remove()
        $(".numbers").html("<div>" + number1 +"</div><div>" + number2 + "</div>")

        $("button.go").on('click' , function(e){
            clicked = true
            console.log($(".input").val()," " ,(number1 + number2))
            //alert(+$(".input").val())
            if(+$(".input").val() == (number1 + number2)){
                 number1 = ~~(Math.random() * 10);
                 number2 = ~~(Math.random() * 10);
                $(".numbers").children().remove()
                $(".numbers").html("<div>" + number1 +"</div><div>" + number2 + "</div>")
            }else{
                clicked  = true
                wrong++
                console.log([number1, number2, number1+ number2])
                if( $.inArray([number1, number2, number1+ number2], wrongQs) == -1){
                    wrongQs.push([number1, number2, number1+ number2])
                    console.log("WrongQs Array " , wrongQs)
                    //wrong = 0
                }

            }
        })
    });
```

html:

```
<div class="numbers"></div>
<input class = "input"> <button class="go">Go</button>
```

Comment: you are creating a new array which is not present in the array even though a similar array exists they are not the same value

Comment: if the array is not present than i would think the test would past `-1 ` means not present I think. i don't understand

Comment: it checks for object equality... not the value of the object(except for primitive values like string, number, boolean)

Comment: thanks. it sounds like you say i shouldn't use $.inArray to check if an array is inside another array. do you have a suggestion on how i could do that.